# JS - Making a hitbox around mouse position in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, collision-detection

happy Sunday!

So, I'm making a silly duck hunt remake just for fun, and I got a question.
What would be the best way to make a hitbox around the mouse cursor in canvas?

This is the code that I use to animate different ducks, and the code to check collision with the edged screen, and bounce them back in another direction.

I know there are probably 100 other ( better ) ways to make this, but I made this from scratch pretty much, and I really like it so far.

So what do I want to do?
I need to kill ducks. So when I click on a duck, I can make it disappear. The disappearing part is not the problem, I am just unsure on how to go on about this.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Here is my code for animation and collision detection:

```js
function animateDuckSprites(ducks) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ducks.forEach((duck) => {
    imageFrameNumber++; // changes the sprite we look at
    imageFrameNumber = imageFrameNumber % totalNumberOfFrames; // Change this from 0 to 1 to 2 ... upto 9 and back to 0 again, then 1...

    ctx.drawImage(
      duck.sprite,
      imageFrameNumber * widthOfSingleImage,
      0, // x and y - where in the sprite
      widthOfSingleImage,
      heightOfImage, // width and height
      duck.x,
      duck.y, // x and y - where on the screen
      widthOfSingleImage,
      heightOfImage // width and height
    );
    checkCollision(duck);
  });
}

function checkCollision(duck) {
  if (
    duck.x + duck.dx > canvas.width - duck.duckSize ||
    duck.x + duck.dx < 10
  ) {
    duck.dx = -duck.dx;
    duck.duckRight = !duck.duckRight;
    duck.sprite.src = duck.duckRight ? duck.spriteRight : duck.spriteLeft;
  }
  if (
    duck.y + duck.dy > canvas.height - duck.duckSize ||
    duck.y + duck.dy < 25
  ) {
    duck.dy = -duck.dy;
  }

  duck.x += duck.dx;
  duck.y += duck.dy;
}
```

Thanks!

edit:
Just came up with this...it kind of works :P

```js
canvas.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (
    e.screenX >= blueDuck.x + 50 &&
    e.screenX <= blueDuck.x + 200 &&
    e.screenY >= blueDuck.y + 160 &&
    e.screenY <= blueDuck.y + 220
  ) {
    console.log("HIT");
  }
});
```

Comment: i mean, register the mouse position, and that's it(?)... is the entire window the canvas element?

Comment: Yeah, the entire window is canvas. I got the screenX / Y coords for the mouse, but just cant get my head around the logic, I think I just need a break lol.

I cant seem to wrap my head around how to actually make a box around the mouse cursor.

Thanks for the reply ! :)

Comment: so you want something like: ok i have a duck which should have a hitbox (unable to find on your code) and if the click of the mouse was inside that hitbox, you want to take out that duck?

Comment: Yeah only the duck doesn't have a hitbox, I was thinking more along the lines if the mouse click is 50px left or right from the duck center ( same with Y ), that's a hit. Should I just make a hitbox for the duck instead ? Like get the top bot left and right of the duck, and then do it that way ?

Comment: Now that you have added the answer to the question, there is no more question. It should be closed or deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just came up with this...it kind of works :P

```js
canvas.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (
    e.screenX >= blueDuck.x + 50 &&
    e.screenX <= blueDuck.x + 200 &&
    e.screenY >= blueDuck.y + 160 &&
    e.screenY <= blueDuck.y + 220
  ) {
    console.log("HIT");
  }
});
```